# Angular material slide toggle does not change after init form

Tags: angular, angular-material

im working angular material components and for some reason, when i initialize the from and set the formcontrol value to `true` on the component, the mat-slide-toggle is not set on the template and is always off / false.

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
    <mat-slide-toggle class="mp-slide-toggle" e2e="edit-service-visibility-toggle" formControlName="visible">{{
        'global.label.visible' | translate
    }}</mat-slide-toggle>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
readonly form = new FormGroup({
    visible: new FormControl(true),
});
```

but if i set the value manually like this `this.form.controls.visible.setValue(true)` then the toggle change, i dont want to change it manually i need the toggle to take the initial value of the form when is initialized

Comment: I don't see any problem with above. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skny6g/. working here.

Comment: @LokeshDaiya that is the weird part, i try also on angular material stackblitz examples and it works just fine, but no idea why in this case does not work.

Comment: what version of angular & angular material you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Do the same on the ngOnInit() method -

```
 ngOnInit(){
readonly form = new FormGroup({
    visible: new FormControl(true),
});
```

This will initialize your form fields to the one set here when the page is initially loaded everytime .

Comment: for this case i can not initialize the form on `ngOnInit` i have this property that depends for the form to be initialize also `protected autoSaveOptions: AutosaveOptions = { autosaveTriggeringObservable: this.form.valueChanges, forms: [this.form] };`